# Smsession without password

Tags: siteminder

I am trying to create the smsession without giving the password. Can I do that by just passing the user id and any other user information of the user but not password and create the smsession?

Answer (score 0):

No. Siteminder uses full credentials to create the smsession.

Answer (score 0):

Raj, You can do that by creating a custom authentication scheme in Java. In code you can always return for authentication so SiteMinder will create a session.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your overall use case is but the IWA Authentication Scheme will let you do perform attribute based authentication. Using the SM SDK, CoreBlox [Note: I work for CoreBlox] has written a Token Service which exposes a RESTful API interface for SiteMinder that allows for this type of integration. You can find out more about it here -- https://www.coreblox.com/products/coreblox-token-service/